# task created through TaskScheduler.dll failed through exception - The data area passed to a system call is too small

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I used `TaskScheduler.dll` (1.0) to create and register a task.
It registers the task and runs on my machine. But when i deployed the 
executable to a diff machine it threw and exception -The data area passed to a system call is too small. (Exception from `HRESULT: 0x8007007A`).

What i could figure out was that the user information was failed to pass to the API but not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

That error is due to a limitation in the OS (depends on Windows version used!) for tasks with user credentials... basically you need to stop the task scheduler service and start it again, wait 10-15 minutes and then try again...

For details see this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264522/en-us).

Comment: I am using this sample code 'td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null)); const string taskName = "Test";
   ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, td);' , never go that error on my machine..and i want this code to run on a user machine so cant start and stop the task scheduler service any other way to get about it ? thanks

Comment: @user1904866 your comment does not help with a solution... please follow the link in my answer and post if any further clarification is needed.